# How to dynamically share input data to parallel processes in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have several parallel processes working on the same data. The said data is composed of 100.000+ arrays (all stored in an HDF5 file, 90.000 values per array).

For now, each process accesses the data individually, and it works well since the HDF5 file support concurrent reading... but only up to a certain number of parallel processes. Above 14-16 processes accessing the data, I see a drop in efficiency. I was expecting it (too many I/O operations on the same file I reckon), but I don't know how to correct this problem properly.

Since the processes all use the same data, the best would be for the main process to read the file, load the array (or a batch of arrays), and feed it to the running parallel processes, without needing to stop them. A kind of dynamic shared memory if you will.

Is there any way to do it properly and solve my scalability issue?

I use the native "multiprocessing" Python library.

Thanks,

Victor

Comment: How many available CPU/threads is in your system and are the lower number of parallel processes already hitting 100% CPU utilization?  How much RAM available vs. dataset size?  Also OS being use can affect this.  Also without knowing what library/framework you are already using with your data it is hard to recommend a specific method to solve your issue as that may be library/framework specific.

Comment: `multiprocessing` has a `Queue` and some other facilities for IPC.

Comment: @metatoaster I'm launching my processes on a university computational grid (tons of nodes, 32 cores each, 96GB of RAM per node). I'm not using any fancy library, only `multiprocessing` for the parallel processing, `h5py` to access the data and `numpy` for the computation.
Os for the OS, its Centos7 I think.
@Klaus_D. I am still fairly new to parallel processing, so I might have missed some of the functionalities of  `multiprocessing`. I'll look a bit more into it but I'd be grateful if you could steer me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: I would recommend searching around for questions that resemble what you are actually doing with those specific libraries and trying out the proposed solutions, and then once you have a better idea of what you need you can then narrow down the scope of the question so someone else might be able to answer it.